# How do I view the tables available in my GridDB database?

Tags: griddb

I've created some tables in my GridDB environment but now want to review which tables have been created. I believe I can see them in the metatables but cannot figure out how to query the tables properly.

I've connected as the GridDB user by doing `sudo su gsadm` and then connected to the shell using `gs_sh` tried `select * from "#tables";` which seems to be a valid query and says 1 results. But how do I view the result?

Answer (score 1):

To view the results after executing my query I needed to execute the `get` command. After doing that I was able to see the results of the query in the terminal